# Execute two commands in single exec() call

Tags: php

I have a function

```
<?php
   $commande ="java -jar file.jar";
   $commande2 ="load file;;";

   //$fichier  ="file.jar";
   exec("$commande");
   exec("$commande2");
?>
```

but the problem is I want to run the second command without closing the terminal. Because if I use `exec ("$ command")`; and `exec ("$ command2")`;
the first command is executed and the terminal is closed after the second command is executed and the terminal is closed.
I want to use PHP `exe`c or other function, to successively execute two commands and do not close the terminal.

Comment: can you do this: `exec("$commande;$commande2");`?

Comment: hm, can you create  a separate bash script that you can call from php and see if you still have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add next line at the end, it will wait till you press *enter* and then close the terminal:

```
fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: hmm, you put that in your php file after `exec("$commande2");` - correct?

Comment: yes i have     exec("$commande");
                     exec("$commande2");fgets(STDIN);

Comment: ok, then in addition to what you already have add this in the first line: `define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));`

Comment: now i don't have a problem , but i don't know why I have not the same result that the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. There are two ways.

The first one is:

`exec('command1 ; command2');`

This will run the command **unconditionally**, which means they don't depend on each other.

However, the second one is:

`exec('command1 && command2');`

This one is **conditional**, The second command **only** runs if the first command  succeeds.

Comment: please the two command if i use terminal  generate file in my current directory,but if i use php to run this command i don't have a generated file